# how I can fix this error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

Tags: c, scip

I am trying this code 
[https://scip.zib.de/doc/html/presol__symmetry_8c_source.php][1]

and I get this error when I run it. Its is a code in C using external library called scip, I used makefile and compile in Mac terminal. I don't know if the problem is from code or what? how I can fix it?

```
 ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

below is a few part after running the problem:

```
`Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
 "_BMSallocBlockMemoryArray_call", referenced from:
  _computeSymmetryGroup in presol_symmetry-8a41e2.o
  _checkSymmetriesAreSymmetries in presol_symmetry-8a41e2.o
  _consdataCreateBinvars in libscip.a(cons_linking.o)
  _consdataCreate in libscip.a(cons_knapsack.o)
  _consPresolXor in libscip.a(cons_xor.o)
  _consCatchAllEvents in libscip.a(cons_linear.o)
  _createRelaxation in libscip.a(cons_and.o)`

 ` "_BMSallocBlockMemory_call", referenced from:
  _SCIPincludePresolSymmetry in presol_symmetry-8a41e2.o
  _SCIPconssetchgAddAddedCons in libscip.a(cons.o)
  _SCIPconssetchgAddDisabledCons in libscip.a(cons.o)
  _SCIPconsCreate in libscip.a(cons.o)
  _SCIPlinConsStatsCreate in libscip.a(cons.o)
  _SCIPincludeConshdlrLinking in libscip.a(cons_linking.o)
  _consdataCreate in libscip.a(cons_linking.o)`
    ...
 ` "_BMSallocBufferMemoryArray_call", referenced from:
  _collectCoefficients in presol_symmetry-8a41e2.o
  _consParseLinking in libscip.a(cons_linking.o)
  _consPrintLinking in libscip.a(cons_linking.o)
  _conflictExecBounddisjunction in libscip.a(cons_bounddisjunction.o)
  _consCopyBounddisjunction in libscip.a(cons_bounddisjunction.o)
  _consParseBounddisjunction in libscip.a(cons_bounddisjunction.o)
  _consPresolBounddisjunction in libscip.a(cons_bounddisjunction.o)`
  ...
 ` "_BMSallocBufferMemory_call", referenced from:
  _SCIPseparateKnapsackCuts in libscip.a(cons_knapsack.o)
  _makeCoverMinimal in libscip.a(cons_knapsack.o)
  _lpbdchgsCreate in libscip.a(conflict.o)`
 ` "_BMSallocClearBlockMemoryArray_call", referenced from:
  _consInitKnapsack in libscip.a(cons_knapsack.o)
  _consInitpreKnapsack in libscip.a(cons_knapsack.o)
  _SCIPmultihashCreate in libscip.a(misc.o)
  _SCIPmultihashInsert in libscip.a(misc.o)
  _SCIPhashtableCreate in libscip.a(misc.o)
  _hashtableCheckLoad in libscip.a(misc.o)
  _SCIPhashmapCreate in libscip.a(misc.o)`
  ...
  `"_BMSallocClearBufferMemoryArray_call", referenced from:
  _computeNOrbitVars in presol_symmetry-8a41e2.o
  _consPresolKnapsack in libscip.a(cons_knapsack.o)
  _SCIPreadProb in libscip.a(scip_prob.o)
  _SCIPvariablegraphBreadthFirst in libscip.a(heur.o)
  _computeReferencePointProjection in libscip.a(cons_quadratic.o)
  _consPresolNonlinear in libscip.a(cons_nonlinear.o)`
 ` "_BMSallocClearMemory_call", referenced from:
  _SCIPsparseSolCreate in libscip.a(misc.o)
  _SCIPdigraphComputeUndirectedComponents in libscip.a(misc.o)
  _SCIPdigraphTopoSortComponents in libscip.a(misc.o)
  _SCIPreoptAddRun in libscip.a(reopt.o)`
`  "_BMSallocMemoryArray_call", referenced from:
  _SCIPsparseSolCreate in libscip.a(misc.o)
  _SCIPprofileCreate in libscip.a(misc.o)
  _SCIPdigraphComputeUndirectedComponents in libscip.a(misc.o)
  _SCIPdigraphTopoSortComponents in libscip.a(misc.o)
  _SCIPdigraphComputeDirectedComponents in libscip.a(misc.o)
  _SCIPchgVarObjProbing in libscip.a(scip_probing.o)
  _SCIPbendersActivate in libscip.a(benders.o)`
```

Comment: There's nowhere near enough information here to actually diagnose your error. Is this a compile time or run time error? What is the compilation command you're using to build your work? What libraries are you using in your code? Post the smallest program you can that fails with the same error.

Comment: these is a line above the error which say : ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64. is it helpful?  I using library scip

Comment: Still not enough information to actually help, but it sounds like you're building an x86_64 binary and you don't have the x86_64 version of your library.

Comment: @David I put the link of the code.

Comment: This is a linker problem, not a compiler problem. The source code is irrelevant here. What is helpful is the actual output from your build process. If it's a long build process then post at a minimum everything after the last command to complete successfully. The problem is that the linker can't find all the symbols it needs to build your program- we can't tell what symbols it's missing, or why they're missing. Maybe you don't have all the dependencies installed for your software. Maybe you have a mix of 32-bit and 64-bit libraries. We just don't know.

Comment: @David could you please check it now?

Comment: There is [extensive documentation about SCIP](https://scip.zib.de/doc-6.0.2/html/). You cannot skip learning C programming and expect people to solve your problems on StackOverflow. Please read the [how-to-ask section](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Those are all functions that are defined in the SCIP source code, so my guess is that you're not building SCIP correctly or you're building for the wrong architecture target (or you have the wrong architecture libraries on your machine). I would look up the installation and build instructions and follow those exactly.